# Custom Filter Datatables Server Side Not Working Codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, datatables, serverside-javascript

Hello I was try to create custom filter with datatables using codeingiter but on submit parameter for custom search not working , but default filter is working success. i was try using browser inspect network but no errors found http alredy 200

My Model Code

```
  public function get_datatables_query()
{
    //add custom filter parameter
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('surat_masuk');
    $this->db->join('kategori', 'kategori.cat_id = surat_masuk.surat_kategori_id');
    $this->db->join('dinas', 'dinas.id_dinas = surat_masuk.surat_dinas_id');
    $this->db->join('users', 'users.id = surat_masuk.surat_user_id');
    $this->db->join('status_surat', 'status_surat.status_surat_id = surat_masuk.surat_status');
    $this->db->where('status_surat_id',2);

    if($this->input->post('index'))
    {
        $this->db->like('surat_id_index', $this->input->post('index'));
    }
    if($this->input->post('nomor'))
    {
        $this->db->like('surat_no', $this->input->post('nomor'));
    }
    if($this->input->post('kode'))
    {
        $this->db->like('surat_kode', $this->input->post('kode'));
    }
    if($this->input->post('kategori'))
    {
        $this->db->where('surat_kategori_id', $this->input->post('kategori'));
    }
    $i = 0;
    //
    foreach ($this->column_search as $item) // loop column
    {
        if(isset($_POST['search']['value'])) // if datatable send POST for search
        {

            if($i===0) // first loop
            {
                $this->db->group_start(); // open bracket. query Where with OR clause better with bracket. because maybe can combine with other WHERE with AND.
                $this->db->like($item, $_POST['search']['value']);
            }
            else
            {
                $this->db->or_like($item, $_POST['search']['value']);
            }

            if(count($this->column_search) - 1 == $i) //last loop
                $this->db->group_end(); //close bracket
        }
        $i++;
    }
    if(isset($_POST['order'])) // here order processing
    {
        $this->db->order_by($this->column_order[$_POST['order']['0']['column']], $_POST['order']['0']['dir']);
    }
    else if(isset($this->order))
    {
        $order = $this->order;
        $this->db->order_by(key($order), $order[key($order)]);
    }
}
///Tampilkan Semua data
public function get_datatables()
{
    $this->get_datatables_query();
    if($_POST['length'] != -1)
    $this->db->limit($_POST['length'], $_POST['start']);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
}
public function count_filtered()
{
   $this->get_datatables_query();
   $query = $this->db->get();
   return $query->num_rows();
}
public function count_all()
{
   $this->db->from('surat_masuk');
   return $this->db->count_all_results();
}
public function get_list_kategori()
{
    $this->db->select('surat_kategori_id');
    $this->db->from('surat_masuk');
    $this->db->order_by('surat_kategori_id','asc');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    $result = $query->result();
    $kategori = array();
    foreach ($result as $row)
    {
        $kategori[] = $row->surat_kategori_id;
    }
    return $kategori;
}
```

My Controller

```
function index()
{
    $this->load->model('admin_kategori/Kategori_model');
    $all_kategori = $this->Surat_masuk_model->get_list_kategori();
    $opt = array('' => 'Semua Kategori');
    foreach ($all_kategori as $all_kategori) {
        $opt[$all_kategori] = $all_kategori;
    }
    $data['kategori'] = form_dropdown('',$opt,'','id="kategori" class="form-control select2"');
    $data['surat_masuk'] = $this->Surat_masuk_model->get_all_surat_masuk_join();
    $data['content'] = 'admin_surat_masuk/v_index';
    $this->load->view('template/v_index',$data);
}
public function ajax_list()
{
     $list = $this->Surat_masuk_model->get_datatables();
     $data = array();
     $no = $_POST['start'];
     foreach ($list as $surat) {
         $no++;
         $row = array();
         $row[] = $no;
         $row[] = $surat->surat_id_index;
         $row[] = $surat->surat_no;
         $row[] = $surat->surat_kode;
         $row[] = $surat->surat_kategori_id;
          $row[] = $surat->cat_name;
         $data[] = $row;
     }

     $output = array(
                     "draw" => $_POST['draw'],
                     "recordsTotal" => $this->Surat_masuk_model->count_all(),
                     "recordsFiltered" => $this->Surat_masuk_model->count_filtered(),
                     "data" => $data,
             );
     //output to json format
     echo json_encode($output);
}
```

My Javascript

```
  <script>
                  var table;
                  $(document).ready(function() {

                      //datatables
                      table = $('#tabel_search').DataTable({

                          "processing": true, //Feature control the processing indicator.
                          "serverSide": true, //Feature control DataTables' server-side processing mode.
                          "order": [], //Initial no order.

                          // Load data for the table's content from an Ajax source
                          "ajax": {
                              "url": "<?php echo site_url('admin_surat_masuk/ajax_list')?>",
                              "type": "POST",
                              "data": function ( data ) {
                                  data.surat_id_index = $('#index').val();
                                  data.surat_no = $('#nomor').val();
                                  data.surat_kode = $('#kode').val();
                                  data.surat_kategori_id = $('#kategori').val();
                              }
                          },

                          //Set column definition initialisation properties.
                          "columnDefs": [
                          {
                              "targets": [ 0 ], //first column / numbering column
                              "orderable": false, //set not orderable
                          },
                          ],

                      });

                      $('#btn-filter').click(function(){ //button filter event click
                          table.ajax.reload();  //just reload table
                      });
                      $('#btn-reset').click(function(){ //button reset event click
                          $('#form-filter')[0].reset();
                          table.ajax.reload();  //just reload table
                      });

                  });

                  </script>
```

My form search custom

```
<form id="form-filter" class="form-horizontal">
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <div class="col-sm-1">
                                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Index" name="index" id="index">
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Nomor Surat" name="nomor" id="nomor">
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Kode" name="kode" id="kode">
                                                    </div>
                                                    <label for="LastName" class="col-sm-1 control-label">Kategori</label>
                                                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                                                        <?php echo $kategori ?>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                                                        <button type="button" id="btn-filter" class="btn btn-primary">Cari</button>
                                                        <button type="button" id="btn-reset" class="btn btn-default">Reset</button>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </form>
```

My table html

```
<table id="tabel_search" class="table table-striped table-bordered" cell-spacing="0">
                              <thead>
                                <tr>
                                  <th class="">No</th>
                                    <th class="">Index</th>
                                  <th>Nomor</th>
                                  <th>Kode</th>
                                    <th>Kategori</th>
                                  <th>Nama Kategori</th>
                                 </tr>
                                                                </thead>
                                                                <tbody>

                                                              </tbody>
                                                          </table>
```

Comment: use `print_r(); die;` and keep debug it. other than i don't thinks so you will get answer here

Comment: i will try sir..thanks for resposns @DeadManAlive